# IIS Manager Crashes after installing Powershell 4.0

Tags: powershell, iis-7

I installed Windows Management (PowerShell 4.0) and all of a sudden my IIS manager is crashing when i try and click on the top level website from the GUI.  I haven't been able to find much on the web about this - any ideas??

Comment: Powershell 4 requires .net 4.5 are  you running windows 7? some thing like EMC dont mesh well with .net 4.5 on windows 7.

Comment: yes, running .NET 4.5.2.

Comment: Are there any error details in the event log? Is AppFabric installed (this is the case when I encountered IIS manager crashing after PS 4.0 installation)?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be related to PowerShell installation. It rewrites the environment variable, but AppFabric 1.1 puts own modules to folder `C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\PowershellModules`(default). If you will try in PS:

```
 Import-Module ApplicationServer
```

and get the error:

> Import-Module : The specified module 'ApplicationServer' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

you should open environment variables typing in Start `edit env` and check that the system variable `PSModulePath` contains this folder:

[image: environment_variables]

And if not - just add it - click Edit..., put in the end `;%ProgramFiles%\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\PowershellModules` and click OK. After open new PowerShell window and try it again:

```
 Import-Module ApplicationServer
```

If no error, you can check that all commands succesfully loaded:

```
 Get-Command –Module ApplicationServer
```

After that IIS Manager succefully expands server and I can see all my websites

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I do have AppFabric installed, and IIS Manager would just crash after it started with an error like

> "Exception:System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: The
>   following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: ,
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\ApplicationServer\Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Management.types.ps1xml:
>   The file was skipped because of the following validation exception:
>   AuthorizationManager check failed."

After I typed in Import-Module ApplicationServer, I did not get an error. I checked my PATH env variables, and the variable was in place. So I restarted IIS Manager and this time it did not crash. So the Import-Module command is what did it.